# callback function of animate not working on ie7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, callback, jquery-animate

i have the following:

```
 $(".transparentLoad").animate({
        opacity : 1,
                },100,function() {
                $(".transparentLoad").each(function(){ alert("IE &");
                                               $(this).css("filter" , " ");
                                           });
                                  });
```

AND also,

```
 $(".transparentLoad").animate({
        opacity : 1,
                },function() {
                $(".transparentLoad").each(function(){ alert("IE &");
                                               $(this).css("filter" , " ");
                                           });
                                  });
```

AND also,

```
    $(".transparentLoad").animate({
            opacity : 1,
                    },{complete:function() {
                    $(".transparentLoad").each(function(){ alert("IE &");
                                                   $(this).css("filter" , " ");
                                               });
                                      }
});
```

But it all gives error in IE7 . What I need to do is that after the animation is done I need to remove the filter css style that gets added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra comma here:

```
opacity : 1, // <----
```

Comment: ohh sure will. Didnt notice this.Will try first . But how come it works just fine on FF and chrome??

Comment: because IE7 and 8 were far more strict with code structure than FF and Chrome.

Comment: Ohk .....This definitely solved it.But ill keep the question as someone else might be getting stuck on this point as there is no duplicate question with this solution.

Comment: The problem with leaving it open is people will find this question when they get a callback that isn't being triggered, then realize that this answer doesn't solve that problem. While this answer did help you, it is of no use to future visitors. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167342/close-all-the-typo-questions